# HOW to use vim to find string with underscore

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace a string IP_HD_LEN using

```
:s/IP_HD_LEN/IP_HDR_LEN
```

in vim
however, I got

```
E486: Pattern not found: IP_HD_LEN
```

what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:%s/IP_HD_LEN/IP_HDR_LEN/g` would be how to do it.

This says search the whole document and do the replacement.

A valid point by @Kent in the comments below.  By adding the `/g` onto the command, you are doing this replacement operation to **every instance** of IP_HD_LEN.  If you wanted to only replace the first instance, you'd skip that and end up with this: `:%s/IP_HD_LEN/IP_HDR_LEN`

Comment: `%s` just means "the whole document" :)  Just the way it is.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace can provide further instruction as to why you need `%s`.

Comment: See `:help range`. `%` is a range from the first line to the last line. Default range is just the current line.

Comment: @ulidtko: Exactly! `.` refers to the current line. A decimal integer refers to a specified line. `$` refers to the last line. A range consists of two line specifications separated by a comma; `:4,6s/foo/bar` performs a replacment on lines 4 through 6. `%` is an abbreviation for `1,$`. The `s` command, like most commands, defaults to `.`, the current line.

Comment: @Daedalus your command replaces more than OP's. (of course if he had `%`). with `/g` it replaces all instances in one line, without the ending `/` just replaces the first matched instance.

Comment: @Kent - my assumption was that this was OP's intention, but you're right... perhaps he only wanted to replace the first such match in which case the `/g` is unnecessary.

Comment: well I knew that comment looks picky, but it would be good if you could mention in your answer, so that OP knows there are two differences between your cmd and his. % and /g. btw, this should be usefule answer. +1

Comment: @Kent - Agreed and so amended :)

Comment: @Daedalus Nice! and ..... keep in mind, vim regex supports look-behind! :D :D :D... I bet nobody understands what I am talking about, but you do. :)

Comment: @Kent - haha... indeed.  indeed.